# Blender or smooth normals of intersecting meshes

Tags: rendering, shaders, normals

Is there an easy way of smoothing the normals of an intersection of 2 meshes (1 object) in the shader properties? I know it can be done with modeling but it could be a real time safer if it can be done some other way.

Any tips are welcome[image]

Comment: If they're separate objects, you can use a data transfer modifier to copy custom normals, generally on nearest face interpolated.  Normals are vertex data, so the closer that vertices are to the join, the better result you'll have.  You can also try using a bevel node in your material, which will try to fake some smoothing of the normals.

Comment: Well its one object but different meshes inside the object. But that means I have to edit the mesh and its topology to make it 1 mesh?

Comment: If you make it one mesh, the problem will solve itself.  If you separate by parts, you can use data transfer like I said.